# LPO, MP and LLPO

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

LPO $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} ( x = 0 \vee x < 0 \vee x > 0)$.

MP $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} (\neg (x = 0) \Rightarrow \vert x \vert > 0)$.

LLPO $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} ( x \ge 0 \vee x \le 0)$.

I was told that in Bishop style constructive mathematics the following holds:

$LPO \Leftrightarrow MP+ LLPO$.

$\Rightarrow$ is easy to show, but I can't verify the other direction. When I looked it up, I only got a theorem

$LPO \Leftrightarrow MP+ WLPO$.

But $LLPO$ does not imply $WLPO$, so I am rather confused.

Comment: What is WLPO?  Do you have a logic statement for that?

Comment: @Bram28 $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} (\neg (0 < x ) \vee \neg \neg (0 < x ))$, see for example Reverse Mathematics in Bishop’s Constructive Mathematics by Hajime Ishihara.

Comment: Where did you see the claim in print? It could be that the claim isn't correct.  These slides seem to claim the equivalence is false in IZF. http://personal.us.es/dfduque/PMR/Lubarsky.pdf  I don't immediately see how anything else in Bishop's system would help.

Comment: @Mauro I don't see how this applies to my problem, sorry.

Comment: Is $x \le 0$ defined as $x <0 \lor x=0$?

Comment: @Carl The first claim was only told in my university. I didn't see it anywhere in print yet. The second is known from a lot of papers.

Comment: @Bram28 - that would usually be read to say that every stage of the approximation of $x$ is consistent with $x$ being $\leq 0$.

Comment: @Bram28 the relations are defined as in the paper Mauro linked (www2.masfak.ni.ac.rs/cmfp2013/Nis%20lecture%20170113.pdf).

Comment: Actually I think that the Hendtlass-Lubarsky paper referred to in the slides that Carl linked to does show that the statement is false (the paper is "Separating Fragments of WLEM, LPO and MP" - https://doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2016.38 ). They claim in Theorem 6.1 to have models of IZF + DC + MP + WKL that don't validate WLPO. As far as I know DC is the only axiom used in Bishop style mathematics not already in IZF, but that holds in the model. Then WKL implies LLPO, and LPO implies WLPO, so LLPO holds in the model but not LPO.